# How do I get different view controllers for a button click in custom table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uibutton

How do I add `viewController` for different clicks in a button given through custom `tableViewCell`? I'm using Swift 4.0.

Comment: do you want to present Viewcontroller on click of a button in tableview cell ????

Comment: yes. different view controllers since I've used table view.

Answer (score 0):

For cellForRowAtIndexPath: method add tag for the button according to index path

```
cell.yourbutton.tag = indexPath.row;
```

Then add target for the button as bellow -

```
[cell.yourbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Swift :

```
cell.yourbutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController. yourButtonClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Now add your code to open a view controller here according to tag type that is your cell index

```
-(void)yourButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
     if (sender.tag == 0) 
     {
         // open view controller for index zero
     }
}
```

Swift -

```
@objc func yourButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton)  {
     if sender.tag == 0
     {
        // open view controller for index zero
     }
}
```